# he was actually checking out

Tags: tense

> *Joe*: …but still, y’know, so, uh, yeah, so when **he was actually
>   checking out** of the hospital, um, they actually told him, “Hey we, we
>   know that you don’t have a job. And you, you told us you don’t have
>   much money. So, uh, y’know, don’t worry about the hundred bucks. Uh,
>   **we’ll** just write it off.”
>
> Source: A.J. Hoge, *Effortless English, Real English Conversation*

May I ask about verb tenses in the context above?

1) Does the verb *will* (in the contraction *we'll*) shows *promises* in the context above?

2) But I am not sure why Joe use *past continuous* verb tense in the first bold part instead of, for example, *simple past*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ "We'll" may indicate a promise to do something, as it appears to in this case, but it may also just show a simple intention to do something which may or may not occur, e.g.:

> I will do my homework after dinner {if I don't forget}.

2/ Check the following site for how the past continuous can be used [(British Council)](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/past-continuous). Based on the dot points at that site, your question is addressed by the first dot point. Checking out of a hospital is a process that can take a few minutes. If the statement in quotation marks was said during that process, then the past continuous would be the correct tense to use.